# Apparently mandatory "reified" keyword introduces weird side effects

Tags: kotlin, generics, interface

I wan't to create a generic class around 2D arrays and enrich it with a bunch of helper functions. But reify keyword is giving me a lot of trouble. Here is a simplified example of what i have and the errors triggered by IJ (please ignore poor construction of object and possible IndexOutOfBoundException) :

```
class MyMatrix<T>(var matrix: Array<Array<T>>) {

    var height = matrix.size
    var width = matrix[0].size

    fun get(x: Int, y: Int): T = matrix[y][x]

    fun set(x: Int, y: Int, data: T) {
        matrix[y][x] = data
    }

    fun dump(transformer: (T?) -> String) {
        println("==== ($width x $height)")
        for (y in 0..<height) {
            print("#${y.toString().padStart(3, '0')} : ")
            for (x in 0..<width) {
                val t = get(x, y)
                print(transformer(t))
            }
            println()
        }
        println()
    }

    fun row(y: Int): Array<T> {
        return matrix[y]
    }

    inline fun <reified U> column(x: Int): Array<U> {
        return Array(height) { y -> matrix[y][x] as U }
    }
}


val aa = Array(3) { y ->
    Array<Int?>(6) { x -> y * 100 + x }
}
val m = MyMatrix(aa)

m.set(1, 1, null)

m.dump { i -> i?.let { "%03d ".format(i) } ?: "--- " }
// ==== (6 x 3)
// #000 : 000 001 002 003 004 005 
// #001 : 100 --- 102 103 104 105 
// #002 : 200 201 202 203 204 205 

// All getters return 204
println(m.get(4, 2))
println(m.row(2)[4])
println(m.column<Int>(4)[2])
```

Before getting to that result, I followed this path of trial and error for the `column` method :

Step A:

```
fun column(x: Int): Array<U> {
   return Array(height) { y -> matrix[y][x] }
}
```

producing the error on "return Array" : "*Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.*"

Step B:

```
inline fun <reified T> column(x: Int): Array<T> {
   return Array<T>(height) { y -> matrix[y][x] }
}
```

With, error on "matrix[y][x]" : "*Type mismatch.
Required: T#1 (type parameter of ...MyMatrix.column)
Found: T#2 (type parameter of ...MyMatrix)*"

Step C:
Naming the 2nd T "U": "Type mismatch. Required: U Found: T"

```
inline fun <reified U>  column(x: Int): Array<U> {
    return Array(height) { y -> matrix[y][x] }
}
```

Step D: adding "as U" as shown in the above snipped.
That seems to work provided i have to change the call site:
`val col = grid.column<Boolean>(x)`

I am really not please with the workaround given that

- implementation and signature is different between methods.
- caller has to adapt
- inlining produce side effects like changing visibility of other attributes/methods of the class / parent class.

I hope i did something wrong given my partial knowledge of generics in Kotlin. What would be the clean way to write a good generic library ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to be clear - your current implementation *works*, but you want to improve the code in `column`. Is that correct?

Comment: Due to type erasure, generics don't mix well with arrays in Kotlin or Java.  Have you considered using Lists (e.g. implemented by ArrayList) instead?

Comment: None of this should be reified, and you shouldn't support U, just T.  No separate types.  It's a little work to make that work, because of how arrays and genetics interact, but it should be doable as long as the matrix is nonempty.

Comment: @Sweeper yes that's the hack introduced in column() and visible with the discrepancy between row() & column()

Comment: @gidds I wanted to stay with native arrays, especially given i would like to have similar class using CharArray or IntArray for performance reasons.  BTW, I couln't find a goodstudy comparing performances between Array<xxxxArray<>>, Array<Array<>> and ArrayList(ArrayList()) in term of initialization, getter, setter and searching though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row` and `column` can be written as extension methods instead.

```
inline fun <reified T> MyMatrix<T>.row(y: Int) =
    Array(width) { x -> get(x, y) }

inline fun <reified T> MyMatrix<T>.column(x: Int) =
    Array(height) { y -> get(x, y) }
```

This way,

- their signatures are consistent
- callers don't need to write the type parameter explicitly
- what they do is also consistent - they both create a *new* array

Note that I'm using `get` - This makes it possible to make `matrix` private.

Also consider making the `get` method an `operator`:

```
operator fun get(x: Int, y: Int): T = matrix[y][x]
```

This allows you to use the `[x, y]` syntax on `MyMatrix`s.

Comment: Thanks! That works and i could add other extensions like cloning..

It's yet magical when considering that an extension is capable of more things that the class itself. Pretty counter intuitive & kind of worrysome i would say.